# Navigation label for page in custom theme

Tags: customization, menus, themes

In Appearance -> Menus, one can change a page´s navigation label. The label is what shows in the menus. However, i´m using a theme with a custom menu, always showing the full page´s title in the menu. Is there a function to fetch the navigation label, so i can edit the theme and use that label instead of get_the_title()?